# How to prepare home to prevent pipe leaks during a severe winter storm?

Tags: plumbing, emergency-preparedness, severe-weather

The news has shown much footage of homes in Texas being destroyed by pipe leaks after a storm hit in February 2021. I live at a similar latitude to the places impacted by the storm, though it did not cause such destruction where I live. What should homeowners do to prepare the home, either in advance, or shortly before such a storm, to avoid having this from happening?

Comment: Provided you have warning, or are at least able to respond quickly, you could drain or at least depressurize the pipes by opening faucets after turning off your mains. If you live in an apt, the best you can do is leave the faucets slightly running and hope for the best. A small obstruction under the toilet flap, like silly putty or tape would cause it to sporadically top-off, relieving pressure behind the fill valve.

Comment: This may be overkill in warmer places as this weather is less common, but I have gone out of my way to make sure I have multiple ways of heating my home. In addition to my furnace and boiler heat, I have a wood stove in the basement and a gas fireplace upstairs that supports running on a 9v battery when there is no main power. Other people have things like generators or large battery backups for their home. In general, it's probably good peace of mind to have at least one kind of 'fall back' so that the power mains going out doesn't create a serious hazard situation.

Comment: You do it when the house is designed/built . Or , that is not possible you do it as soon as you can , not after a disaster is forecast.

Comment: We sometimes get long outages in winter - not often. The basic water entry is always below frost line, and if there isn't no-power-needed backup heat or a functional generator to keep the heat on, I'll drain the plumbing when it becomes clear that it's gone on too long - but of course our houses are well insulated and our pipes are not normally exposed to the cold side of that, so there's typically going to be 24 hours or more before things freezing is an issue, and that's an unusual but not unheard of outage.

Comment: @isherwood you probably have better insulation as well as more reliable heat.  The insulation is key because it buys you loads of time

Comment: You may want to update your title.  Most of the world did not experience any storms in 2021 February.  It may be a revelation, but the weather in the rest of the world does not match that in Texas USA.  Thankfully.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The world is big, and a lot of places are frequently experiencing frost that's as strong or stronger than in Texas recently. It may well be that the tropics are more *populous* -- India has 1366 million inhabitants, Siberia and Canada 34/37 million. The problem in Texas is surely that it was an uncommon event that buildings and infrastructure are not prepared to handle, compounded by the much-discussed deregulated energy market there.

Comment: @isherwood: if you have a power outage in the MN winter cold enough to get uncomfortable, you might as well drain your plumbing. It would only take a few minutes to do so, and since the main into the house is below the frost line, doing so would completely protect you. Why chance it?

Comment: Pipe heating and enough solar,wind, and battery power to guarantee the furnace keeps running. Either that or enough for space heaters in each room.

Comment: Long in advance everyone in the extreme north buries there water,sewer, and gas pipes at least 6 feet down.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The cheapest thing to do, and feasible to do at the very last minute without any supplies, is to shut off the water at an underground location outside the building (at the meter, for instance). Iced pipes, and even broken pipes, aren't what causes severe damage to a building -- it's the water that flows uncontrolled after a frozen and broken pipe thaws that really causes havoc.

I don't have statistics handy for the average length of piping used in a US home, but just to work with round numbers, suppose it's 100 feet of 3/4 inch pipe and 200 feet of 1/2 inch pipe. Combined all that pipe holds about 6.5 gallons of water.

That's not an insignificant amount of water, but chances are that a leak in some arbitrary place isn't going to allow *all* of that to leak out, either. A good portion of the pipe contents could be drained out before the freeze by opening faucets. High-elevation faucets will admit air into the system while low-elevation faucets let the water run away down the drain.

Don't forget to also drain other reservoirs of chaos: toilet tanks and water heater tank. Extra credit goes to one who treats the P-traps too. Those under sinks could be removed and the water simply dumped out. Those under bathtubs, built into toilets, or hidden in the wall for a clothes washer could be vaccumed out with a wet-dry vac or even a turkey baster, or treated with salt or RV antifreeze to prevent the remaining water from freezing.

Water-using appliances are likely to be damaged but freeze-proofing them is challenging. Think about the in-door water dispenser or ice maker in a fridge, the dish washer, the clothes washer, the steam feature in a clothes dryer, a steam oven, and so on..

After the storm is over and temperatures return above freezing careful re-commissioning of the water system is key. Verify the drainage plumbing is undamaged (traps below sinks, bathtubs, clothes washers, etc). Test the supply plumbing for leaks with vacuum or compressed air if possible. Turn the water on slowly and carefully listen and watch for signs of leaks. Monitor the flow indicator and dials on the water meter to confirm water flows only when it's expected to (when a valve somewhere is opened).

Comment: "And a good portion of it could likely be drained out before the freeze by opening a low-elevation faucet." This idea is an important part of the preparation and it should follow the first sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: @erickson Also note that this can go faster if you also open a high-elevation faucet.  That allows air to flow in at the top, and water at the bottom, instead of forcing air to pass the water in the pipes.

Comment: @Yakk : it's a good idea to open the low tap, then *all* of the higher taps, so you can get air behind them.  But you often don't need to do this before a storm.  Depending on how much insulation you have, and if you lose your sources of heat, you might have a day or two before you need to worry.  (I start getting worried as the house starts dipping below 50°F, and try to get things drained before it gets below 40°F).  Oh, and around me, meters are inside the house ... but there's a street shutoff (but you need a "curb wrench" to get in there)

Comment: "...other reservoirs of chaos..."  Good one.

Answer (score 24):

### Use the Minnesota and California building codes

That's to protect you from freeze and [earthquakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Virginia_earthquake).  ([New Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Madrid_Seismic_Zone) fault, yo).

There are a thousand little details in home construction that differ between warm places and cold.  I come from the snow belt, and am constantly looking at sun-belt houses going "Wow, I guess you can do that here".  Bare water main popping out of the ground and going into the house, "sure, why not".   In the midwest that's buried below the frost-line, all the way into climate controlled space (e.g. basement).

Look at how they design buildings, how they avoid e.g. putting water pipes on exterior walls, etc.  Use that as a guide when doing renovations.

If you see any "low hanging fruit" opportunities to move a pipe from the outside of the house's insulation envelope to the inside... take it.

If you have areas you just can't protect, I'd advise a combination of hyperinsulation + thermal mass, and "heat tape".   Electric  heat tape actively warms the pipes (when electricity is available).

Hyper-insulation of pipes *slows the inevitable*. Let's say you do a great job of insulating the pipe, and at 5 degrees F, it loses 1 BTU per hour.  (1 BTU = energy to make 1 pound of water rise or fall 1 degree F.)  The problem is, the pipe is small and doesn't contain much water. If it has a half pound, and started at 50F (18 degrees to freezing), it only has 9 BTUs  to lose before it starts to freeze.  My answer is to *greatly increase* the thermal mass that is inside the hyperinsulation wrappings, by adding water volume to it.  2-litre soda bottles will suffice - cheap and expendable. Hyper-insulate all that - the surface area is much larger, so it will lose, say 5 BTUs/hour.  But now if it has 20 pounds of water instead of 0.5 pounds, it now has 180 BTUs to give up! *That's more like it*.

That, *plus* heat tape is a winning combination, because it means the pipe (and bottles) have as many BTUs as possible *to start with*, and it only has to make it across the lesser of the power outage and the cold snap.

### Have a generator *interlock*, for Pete's sake

This is a simple "sliding plate" affair that prevents *both* the main and an installed breaker from being switched on.  Nothing more than that.

Generators (or much better, electric cars with inverters such as the 2004 Silverado Hybrid) are now so prolific that almost anyone could be in a situation of having power out and also having a generator.  Without the necessary "bit" to connect them, tragedy happens, **[to](https://www.npr.org/2019/12/04/784279242/carbon-monoxide-poisoning-from-portable-generators-proves-predictable-and-deadly) the [point](https://www.npr.org/2020/09/01/908515238/majority-of-hurricane-laura-deaths-linked-to-improper-use-of-portable-generators) where [major](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/briannasacks/louisiana-grandmother-family-killed-generator-hurricane)-storm [events](https://portal.ct.gov/DPH/Press-Room/Press-Releases---2011/January-2011/Department-of-Public-Health-Warns-of-Dangers-of-Carbon-Monoxide-Poisoning-During-Power-Outages) now [accrue](https://www.dailysentinel.com/social_media/article_a7efd263-7e51-56ba-bbde-9ed90e9dfdb8.html) most [of](https://www.koco.com/article/two-people-die-due-to-carbon-monoxide-poisoning-linked-to-generators-inside-structures-okc-fire-officials-say/34535620#) their fatalities from generator misuse**.  I hate generators with the heat of 1000 suns, but I feel every house should have an interlock that lets them cut over either the entire panel, or a critical-loads subpanel, over to generator *because this is better than dying*.

*A lot of the deaths aren't Darwin awards. A lot of people did stuff that seemed perfectly reasonable, and were blindsided by circumstances.*

Note that a $350 "transfer switch" is a weak way to do this - it's expensive and supports only 6, 8 or 10 circuits. It should not be used, unless dealing with an extremely archaic panel for which an interlock is simply impossible. *But even then, an $80 "critical loads" subpanel is a better way to do this, and far cheaper as well*.

Most panels support a simple $25-$80 sliding-plate interlock between the main breaker and one other breaker ($10).  That breaker is then wired to a generator "inlet" in an appropriate location.  Shut all breakers off; turn the generator backfeed breaker on; then turn on select loads.

### Have an auxiliary furnace

One thing that blows my mind is all the houses in the snowbelt with gas heat, *which cannot function if electricity is not also present*.  That's just not a problem in the Sunbelt, as we have the famous Empire style wall or floor furnace - a gas-fired, convection-circulated furnace.  They work fine during outages as they do not use electricity at all (except for millivolts which they generate with their own thermocouple; this allows use of an external thermostat).

It helps to design a house *around* such a furnace, as convection is the name of the game. But even if not, they will add enough heat to the building envelope to at least prevent freeze.

The units are inexpensive - under $1000 for a 50,000 BTU unit.  They do require a vent stack, of course, and they do draw negative pressure on the building where that is a concern.  There may be types which draw intake air from outside, but being unpowered makes that a design challenge.

Comment: Minnesotan here. Some interesting ideas, but I'm not sure how practical. The water mass thing has me wondering how you'd implement that over a lengthy and complicated system. Generators with interlocks are a good idea, but that means _everyone has to own one_. Yikes. We're talking Y2K-level generator sales, and most won't start due to neglect when the time comes. As to aux furnaces... I have one like you describe in my garage. I'm not sure how I'd get its heat to all the concealed and remote pipes in my home. Maybe, if it ran full time, but without fans to distribute heat it would be sketchy.

Comment: If a pipe can't be relocated to a more freeze-resistant location but can be accessed to allow strapping on thermal mass it could instead be replaced with a much larger size. A 1/2" pipe holds 0.09 lb of water per foot while 2" holds 1.36 lb/ft. The 2L soda bottle brings even more mass (4.4 lb/ft), but outrageously oversizing the pipe might be more.. neat or clean? Oversizing is not a great choice for a hot water line of course.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that sometimes it's easier to move the building envelope outside the pipes, rather than moving the pipes inside.  For example, if the pipes are running through an attic floor, it's very likely cheaper and easier to just throw a thick layer of cellulose on top rather than try to insulate each pipe individually.

Comment: Running the water keeps the pipes from freezing if they have some insulation. But people have to know how much flow is needed and many do not. A lot of people in Dallas let the faucets "drip"; this is not nearly enough flow to prevent freezing.

Comment: @isherwood I think generators are stupid, and I don't propose having a generator at the ready, just having the interlock at the ready.  That way,  if a generator *does* make an appearance, and you don't become yet another generator tragedy, which is the #1 way Americans die in storms.

Comment: How do people manage to kill themselves with generators? I can easily imagine big sparks and damaged generators. But *death*?

Comment: Carbon monoxide and improper backwiring.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I lived through 9 days without power and you couldn't buy a generator anywhere with 50-100 miles.  I had to bring one in from another state.  If you need one, I don't think you can count on being able to buy one at that moment.  Also, most of the gas stations were either unable to turn their pumps on or process credit card transactions.  No ATMs either.  So if you could find a generator, there were long lines at the few open stations and it was cash only.  That is once me and my neighbors cut a path through all the downed branches on the street.

Comment: @user253751 Big sparks and gasoline are also a pretty bad combination.

Comment: @JimmyJames a friend of mine got a generator the day before a hurricane hit her state last year.  The catch is that she ended up with a several thousand dollar (diesel???) generator that was big enough she could barely move it because that was what the local boxmart had gotten a trailer load of a few hours before; vs the much smaller and cheaper model that she wanted and was all she needed.

Comment: @user253751 I know, right? But it's true.  CO poisoning is top of the chart. And many aren't even Darwin awards; they're people making *what seem like perfectly reasonable concessions* to the CO issue,  and it's not enough. This could even happen with a permanently installed generator if a wrong-way wind meets a cracked door.  Scary.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight For several thousand dollars, I'd get a 7 KWH block out of a Tesla Model S pack (~$1000), top shelf inverter ($300), critical loads panel with interlock ($90), top shelf Morningstar solar charge controller ($300) and $500-1000 on solar panels (500-1000W). We could run indefinitely the fridge, LED lights, gas on-demand water heater, router, and tablets.  We'd be safe, warm, lit, fed and entertained.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I think a lot of CO issues are that people put the generator in their garage to keep it out of the elements and avoid it being stolen.  The same challenge goes for using a hybrid as a generator. I know someone who did that and had a exhaust extension for that reason.  Depending on where you live, you  may not want to leave your running vehicle outside.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica oh well since we were talking about wiring I was assuming it would be some kind of wiring issue

Comment: OTOH, CO isn't always the issue. My next door neighbor nearly burned her house down just after Christmas with a small propane heater running inside. Note that this was for aux heat, as the power was on (I always see her TV flickering through the window) and it wasn't sub-zero temps.

Comment: I love my interlock. Electrician came over to quote on it, had never heard of one! So I did it myself (and had it inspected).

Comment: @StayOnTarget my hunch is they pay a pretty good sales commission on those 6/8/10 circuit transfer switches, to get the trade motivated into going to those as a *first* resort instead of a last resort as they should be.

Comment: Not sure California building code is enough. For example, we have plenty of pipes exposed outdoors.

Comment: @bbodenmiller I said Minnesota and California building codes.  I didn't mean Minnesota for earthquakes and California for pipe protection LOL.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't read that as needing to follow both.

Answer (score 10):

If you accept that more weather extremes are likely, then moving to setting up the water system in a way that it's less likely to actually freeze, as we do in the (traditional) colder areas might look worthwhile. However, to your question:

Your basic approach, for a more limited set of changes, in advance, make sure that you can (and know how to, and preferably have documented for the rest of your family, or the next owner of your house) turn off your water supply & drain your pipes as fully as possible. This might involve adding some drain valves at low points, if the system is not currently set up for that.

In the event, you should turn off your water supply and drain the pipes, the water heater, the water softener, etc..., and put RV anti-freeze (which you will have stockpiled in advance for the event, rather than try to go buy while the shelves are empty - or salt solution if you miss that point) into the toilets and other traps (maintaining the trap seal while preventing damage from freezing.)

That should isolate any freeze damage to the water supply system side of the supply valve. If you are on a well, you may have more area you are personally responsible for (and you would turn off the well pump power supply, rather than shutting off the supply valve.)

Comment: If you have a well, just leave a faucet somewhat open and let it flow. If you're flowing 0.1 GPM,  you're not taxing the pump and the water won't freeze.

Comment: No power, no flow. Loss of power is a main complicating factor you have to plan for. If you assume power will be available, you could heat trace & insulate all the piping

Comment: In a lot of houses in Dallas the piping is inaccessible inside (poorly insulated) walls. In our house the kitchen faucet is the only one on an outside wall. I put a foam camping sleeping pad against the outside wall to reduce heat flow, opened, under sink cabinet and let the kitchen faucet run. I did all this AFTER I discovered the kitchen faucet frozen (hot and cold) and quickly thawed it with a 1600 W hair dryer aimed at the outside edge of the slab.

Answer (score 5):

Here in Minnesota, it's pretty common that a house needs to be winterized. That was especially true about 10 years ago during the surge in foreclosures that left a lot of homes vacant for many months until the banks could move ahead with selling the property. The other answers hit a lot of the key points, but I'll add a few that will more or less guarantee that the plumbing will survive even a hard freeze.

- Turn off the water at the most upstream valve you are able to access. Ours are usually in the front yard at the bottom of a vertical pipe, and require a special wrench called a "street key" to reach them.
- Open all of the faucets, sillcocks, and drain ports. Turn on all tubs and showers.
- Switch the water softener to bypass mode and follow manufacturer instructions to relieve the pressure and drain the tank. Dump out the brine tank and make sure the head is drained.
- Empty the water heater, including any water that might be left in the expansion tank (if you have one). **Set the thermostat to "OFF"** (Gas) or **turn off (and lock out, if possible) the breaker** (Electric)
- Disconnect any other appliance that has a water supply line (washing machine, ice maker, fridge, dish washer, etc...). Drain them according to instructions.
- If you have an air compressor, connect it to the system and blow out any water that remains (not strictly needed but if you have a compressor, it's extra insurance)

That takes care of the supply lines, but you should also prepare the waste side of the plumbing system.

- Flush all toilets and hold down the handle until the tank is completely empty (the flapper will generally close well before the tank is fully drained if you don't hold it open).
- Remove traps from under sinks and tubs/showers and empty them out. replace them and stuff rags into the drain to block sewer gas and rats/cockroaches/other bad stuff.
- any drains that you are not able to fully empty should be filled with anti-freeze. This includes any floor drains, clean-outs, and buried drain pipes that might hold water.
- fill toilet bowls with anti-freeze and seal the bowl with shrink wrap to keep them from drying out.

Comment: If I were to buy a house protected in this way, I would be very grateful to find a list of all these things and how to get everything working again.

Answer (score 2):

## Gas/Propane heat + a way to hook to a generator

My in-laws had a severe ice storm a few years ago (no power for 36 hours) and my father-in-law knew how to pull the power line to the HVAC system and run the blower off his generator.

Harper's interlock sounds good, but a cheaper DIY solution (provided you're comfortable with your electrical panel) is doing this a [double-pole double-throw switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003AUIRDE) coupled with an [inlet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ATXIBG) (15A shown but you can find 20A varieties). Your DPDT switch can switch power from the breaker box to your generator (NEVER backfeed your generator into the panel), and the inlet lets you plug a standard extension cord up. Make sure you get enough wattage to run your HVAC blower by itself. In most cases they take 20A or less (my FIL ran his on an 1800W invetor generator and most truck generators are in the 2000W range). This setup is simple enough for anyone to use.

Why not an interlock? Aside from the cost of the interlock and likely an electrician, you might not want to try to power your whole house off one generator. The best you can do is 30A 240v off one outlet. It will run your lights, TV and most electronics (provided it's an inverter generator). You can even squeeze an appliance or two in (my fridge is 3A). But if you're running all that and your furnace blower kicks in (or worse, electric heat), you might be over budget. Extension cords are a better way to hook up individual devices as you need them.

If you really want to run your whole house, just buy a whole-house generator. Not only do they provide more than enough power, they typically include the interlock (plus they generally start automatically).

Comment: Even if the gas supply goes down, a dumb 3kW generator running electric heaters in a house with decent  insulation should keep things from freezing solid for a couple of days (while being far from comfortable) - plan C, behind your suggestion of running the electric parts of a gas heating system off it.

Comment: ...We have a couple of advantages where I am: 230V for everything, and the electrical demands of our water-filled gas heating systems are lower - the exhaust fan from the boiler (furnace) and a water pump, so I could use a sub-kW generator to run the heating and fridge with just a little rewiring on the heater circuit.  I could probably run the heating for a few hours/day off a small inverter and the 100Ah battery from my campervan

Answer (score 2):

When we had our last big freeze in Ireland, our house was saved by a dripping tap that I had not got around to replacing. There was a constant small flow of water so nothing froze up. We supplied four other houses for a week that winter!

Comment: This works, with a small caveat: a "drip" should be a very slow but nearly continuous trickle of water. if you can count the drips, it's too slow.

Comment: You describe it exacty. It was months waiting for me to replace and what had begun as countable drops had become a small flow by the time the freeze arrived.